# What is the meaning of "get on" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

Is this correct grammar?

> My teacher taught me what kind of work should be done if you want to **get** on in all aspects of your work.

What does *get on* mean here?

Comment: The meaning of *get on* is clear in the context of the sentence. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's grammatical.

In this example, *get on* means

verb
[INTRANSITIVE] BRITISH to be successful in life or at work
*He is prepared to do anything in order to get on.*

-- http://www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/dictionary/british/get-on#get-on__16

Comment: To get on is not only British. If you use get on in AmE in many contexts such as this one, anyone pretty much will understand that it means get ahead.

Comment: Tnx.. but what is the meaning of get ahead ?

Comment: @Maryprincess55321 to be successful

Comment: @Lam Interesting. My own sense is that it seems quite British. I think I'd (I'm American) interpret the meaning in the OP's sentence as something like *continue* or *move ahead.* And the example sentence from the dictionary, in my answer, strikes me as foreign. I wonder if it relates primarily to how much exposure to BrE we may have had.

Comment: @JIm Reynolds When AmE speakers say: How is x/are or are pronoun/person getting on? It's the same meaning. Or: We need to get on with it [as in this project]. I see no difference in meaning.

Comment: @Lam in your first example, it does not equal *How are you getting ahead?* It is related, but different. In your second example, it means to continue, not to *get ahead.* See the phrasal verb here: https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=get+on

Comment: @Jim Reynolds You keep misspelling my screen name. I disagree but am too weary to battle it out. Sorry.